# Why Reactjs doesn't load component content?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-router-dom

I'm working on a reactjs front end, and in my app.js i have this following code :

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Switch, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './Components/Login.component';
import Register from './Components/Register.component';
import Home from './Components/Home.component';
import Services from './Components/Services.component';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import './App.css';

function Index() {
return(
<div className="container-fluid index-container" style={{backgroundImage:"url(indexBackground.png)"}}>
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light index-navbar">
      <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img className="img-fluid" width="110" src="logo.png" alt="logo"></img>
      </a>
      <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link" href="#">Acceuil</a>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link" href="#">Actualités</a>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link" href="#">Nos services</a>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link" href="#">Nos vehicules</a>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link" href="#">Contactez-nous</a>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link" href="#">Se connecter</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="index-container-x" className="row d-flex align-items-center" style={{display:"none"}}>
      <div className="col-lg-6 index-container-x justify-content-center">
        <h1 className="white-heading">Découvrez la location longue durée nouvelle génération</h1>
        <hr style={{borderColor:"#fff"}} />
        <Link className="btn btn-primary" to="/Register">S'abonner</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
 )
}
function App() {
 return (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
      <Index />
    </Route>
      <Route path="/Login">
        <Login />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/Register">
        <Register />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/Home">
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/Services">
        <Services />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
  );
  }
 export default App;
```

I also have a home component with the following code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import '../App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './Navbar.component';
import Chart from './Chart.component';

class Home extends Component {
render() {
    return(
        <Router>
            <Navbar />
            <Chart />
        </Router>
    )
   }
}
export default Home;
```

Here is my navbar component :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js';
import '../App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
      return(

            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light blue-nav">
            <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/Home">
                <img alt="nothing" width="110" src="logo.png"></img>
            </Link>
            <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/Home"><i className="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i> Tableau de bord</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/Services"><i className="fas fa-hand-holding-heart"></i> Nos services</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/Contracts"><i className="fas fa-folder-open"></i> Mes contrats</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/Vehicles"><i className="fas fa-car"></i> Mes vehicules</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/Notifications"><i className="fas fa-bell"></i> Notifications <span className="badge badge-danger">4</span></Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/Support"><i className="fas fa-question-circle"></i> Aide</Link>
                </li>

                </ul>
                <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                    <Link className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" to="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i className="fas fa-user-cog"></i> Compte
                    </Link>
                    <div className="dropdown-menu dropdown-menux" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <Link className="dropdown-item" to="#"><i className="fas fa-user-circle"></i> Modifier mon profile</Link>
                    <Link className="dropdown-item" to="#"><i className="fas fa-lock"></i> Sécurité</Link>
                    <Link className="dropdown-item" to="#"><i className="fas fa-cogs"></i> Paramètres</Link>
                    <div className="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <Link className="dropdown-item" to="#"><i className="fas fa-power-off"></i> Se déconnecter</Link>
                    </div>
                </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </nav>

      )
  }
}
export default Navbar;
```

Now what i want to do is when i click the LINK in the navbar (services Or Home) i want that route's component to be rendered, but the problem i have in the browser link it showes localhost:3000/Services but the content of Home component still shows up like there was never a new page navigation.

Here is my services component :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import '../App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './Navbar.component';

class Services extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
  }
  render() {
      return(
        <Router>
            <Navbar />
        </Router>
     )
  }
}
export default Services;
```

Here is some images :

1st image is for the Home before the click of the Link :
2nd image is for the Services page after the link is clicked : (no services content)

[image]

[image: After the Link is clicked]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `Navbar` to main App.js and don't use `Router` inside Router (i.e. Home and Services pages)

```js
function App() {
 const key = Date.now();
 return (
  <Router>
    <Navbar />
    <Switch>
    <Route key={key} exact path="/">
      <Index />
    </Route>
      <Route key={key} exact path="/Login">
        <Login />
      </Route>
      <Route key={key} exact path="/Register">
        <Register />
      </Route>
      <Route key={key} exact path="/Home">
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route key={key} exact path="/Services">
        <Services />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
  );
  }
 export default App;


class Home extends Component {
render() {
    return(<Chart />)
   }
}
export default Home;


class Services extends Component {
render() {
    return(<ServciesContent />)
   }
}
export default Home;
```

Comment: It's working and the main problem was solved, Thank you, but there is just this one conflict, when i navigate to the services and go back again, that chart doesn't load the content, i'm using chat.js in order to handle the chart values, may be it has to do with the index.html ? since i'm putting the script that renders the canvas in the index.html file.

Comment: Bad fix will be https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/forcerefresh-bool

Comment: forcing the refresh every time the page will load is bad  ? why if you'll excuse me please ?

Comment: In Single Page App, usually only inside content changes with change in route but reloading whole app is not efficient. extra api calls will be made which will not be needed

Comment: Another option is to create a key like `const key = Date.now()` and pass it to each route. Let me update the code and try this if it helps

Comment: I'm working on it, a lot of changes needed to be done because of this architecture xD

Comment: @JesseLucas Best of luck